# Java multiplayer cards game

Tags: java, networking, card-game

I need to develop a simple multiplayer card game. For example, a poker game; this is only for study. I am going to develop it in Java.

How I can I manage communication between the server and clients? Can I use sockets for this game?

Edit: Thanks, I know socket programming. I know the programming socket. I just wanted to know if it was the correct technique for a multiplayer game like online poker.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, sockets would work just fine. There's a great tutorial using Java, that not only shows you how to use the sockets, but also teaches you about the underlying fundamentals. The tutorial can be found here:

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3218/java_network_game_programming.php

Make sure you look at all 3 of the tutorial.

And the entire source code for the tutorial is found here:

http://www.gamasutra.com/features/19970812/netcon4.zip