# Better ways of handling the server for a Multiplayer Browser Based Game

Tags: multiplayer, server

I am looking to create a multiplayer browser based game, similar to tribal wars and such, and i'm trying to think of better ways of handling the server, for example when troops and buildings are completed and the landing of troop movements

Comment: How are you storing your data?  Does it live in ram, a database, or what?

Comment: What's your actual question? What problem specifically are you trying to solve? Your question is pretty broad and vague as it is.

Comment: It will be stored in a database

Comment: Ways which are better than *what* exactly? What did you try and in what regard did it fail to fulfill your requirements?

Answer (score 7):

Tribal Wars is a browser-based, massive multiplayer online real time strategy game, set in the Middle Ages.

Now Tribal Wars is a browser based game and was released in 2003 as a text based game.

Browser-based games usually rely on some kind of server-side code, such as Perl, PHP, Ruby, Python, or Java; though some will use technologies like Flash, ActiveX, and Java applets to store data on the client's computer.

Unlike a stand-alone client or video game, being confined to a browser limits to some degree the extent to which 3-D rendering can be supported.

**The following resources may help you**

**Basic Guideline**

- http://marakana.com/training/html5/websocket_for_social_gaming.html
- http://www.startupmonkeys.com/2010/09/building-a-scrabble-mmo-in-48-hours/
- http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/
- http://www.openskies.net/files/Openskies_MMPOG.pdf

**HTML5**

- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/2012/01/18/spaceshoot-multiplayer-game-tutorial-html5/
- http://www.pubnub.com/game/html5-multiplayer
- http://blog.clay.io/writing-a-multiplayer-game-with-html5s-canvas

**Flash**

- http://playerio.com/documentation/tutorials/building-flash-multiplayer-games-tutorial/
- http://wiki.whirled.com/Multiplayer_server_based_game_%28ActionScript_tutorial%29

**Java**

- http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3218/java_network_game_programming.php
- http://www.gamasutra.com/features/19970812/netcon4.zip

**Community Resources**

- [Java multiplayer cards game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12085/java-multiplayer-cards-game)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513939/multiplayer-game-development
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098611/multiplayer-game-architecture

**EDIT :**

> better ways of handling the server, for example when troops and buildings
>   are completed and the landing of troop movements

**You should have persistent connection with server as every connection takes time for extra resource, Point-to-point connection, Low latency for better interaction.**

It varies from platform to platform. For example, for browser game **tribal wars** used the followings

- Server End Code # **PHP**, Some **Java**
- Server # **Amazon**: **EC2, CloudFront, S3, Hadoop/Elastic Map Reduce,
  Hive, some SQS, some SimpleDB**
- Load Balancing # **HAProxy**
- Sharded, Blob Storage # **MySQL**
- Point-to-point connectivity # **YAMI4**
- Low latency # **YAMI4**

Comment: Everything on client side i know how to do, its just the best way to get the server to run the events such as building completed, adding troops, attacks, and so forth

Comment: @CraigWeston, it depends on which platform do you want to use. It varies platform to platform.

Comment: @CraigWeston, I have edited my answer regarding "the best way to get the server to run the events such as building completed, adding troops, attacks, and so forth". Thanks for comment. :)